# Windows Explorer Shell Extension: create file and enter "rename" mode

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

For a shell  extension (UI is similar to "New/" context menu), I need to create a file, select it and enter "rename" mode, so the user can adjust the default name.

Q: How do I enter "rename" mode for a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use [IShellView::SelectItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the [SVSI_EDIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't expect any answer anymore, and yes, that's how it should be done :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending "F2" to the window?

Comment: Sending keystrokes isn't really the solution I'm looking for - besides, this would require selecting the file first. Further problems: refresh and wait for the new file to be actually listed, and selecting the file