# Select a file for renaming in SharpShell context menu

Tags: c#, windows-shell, sharpshell

I'm using SharpShell to write a tiny new shell context menu item that *copies the currently selected files to a new subfolder, then prompts the user for the directory's new name*.

Searching StackOverflow, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647447/send-folder-rename-command-to-windows-explorer) answer. However, I'd like to do the same in SharpShell.

I will somehow have to fire `SVSI_EDIT` at it, which I can find buried deep in `SharpShell.Interop`, but I'm not sure how any of this works. I can't find any documentation or code samples whatsoever.

(Edit: I think finding out how to get a `Pidl` from a file name would be a good start, but maybe I don't really need that at all?)

Comment: When you create a new folder using Explorer, it names the folder "New Folder", and then it enters rename mode. When you are typing the folders name and then pressing enter, you are actually renaming the folder. What happens if the user renames the folder, then presses enter before the files finish copying? The rename will probably fail because the files are still being copied to the folder. I think this approach is not good and you are better off showing a form with a text box to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start creating a project with *SharpShell* to register a new shell context menu like in this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus).

Here, we have to define a class implementing `SharpContextMenu`. For simplicity we will create the menu for any filetype and always show it:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.AllFiles)]
public class CopyFilesExtension : SharpContextMenu
{
    protected override bool CanShowMenu()
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override ContextMenuStrip CreateMenu()
    {
        var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();

        var copyFiles = new ToolStripMenuItem { Text = "Copy Files To Folder..." };

        copyFiles.Click += (sender, args) => CopyFiles();
        menu.Items.Add(copyFiles);

        return menu;
    }

    private void CopyFiles()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But I'm sure you've done all this, the problem here is to implement the `CopyFiles()` method.

One way to do this is showing a dialog asking for the name of the folder, something like this:

[image: CopyFilesDialog]

Then, implement `CopyFiles()` like so:

```
private void CopyFiles()
{
    using (var dialog = new CopyFileDialog())
    {
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(SelectedItemPaths.First());
            var newFolder = Path.Combine(folder, dialog.FolderName);

            Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolder);

            foreach (var path in SelectedItemPaths)
            {
                var newPath = Path.Combine(newFolder, Path.GetFileName(path));
                File.Move(path, newPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In above code, we asked for the name of the folder, then create the folder and finally move selected files to that folder.

**However**, if you want to do it using *Rename* command in *Windows Explorer* we can start by importing some needed *Win32* functions:

```
class Win32
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr ILCreateFromPath([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszPath);

    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern int SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(IntPtr pidlFolder, uint cidl, IntPtr[] apidl, int dwFlags);

    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern void ILFree(IntPtr pidl);
}
```

- `ILCreateFromPath` allows us get the *PIDL* from a filename.
- `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems` allow us select the file and send rename command.
- `ILFree` frees unmanaged `PIDL` created.

With these *Win32* functions we can defines `CopyFiles()` as follows:

```
private void CopyFiles()
{
    var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(SelectedItemPaths.First());
    var newFolder = Path.Combine(folder, "New Folder");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolder);

    foreach (var path in SelectedItemPaths)
    {
        var newPath = Path.Combine(newFolder, Path.GetFileName(path));
        File.Move(path, newPath);
    }

    RenameInExplorer(newFolder);
}


private static void RenameInExplorer(string itemPath)
{
    IntPtr folder = Win32.ILCreateFromPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(itemPath));
    IntPtr file = Win32.ILCreateFromPath(itemPath);

    try
    {
        Win32.SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(folder, 1, new[] { file }, 1);
    }
    finally
    {
        Win32.ILFree(folder);
        Win32.ILFree(file);
    }
}
```

We can't use `SharpShell.Interop.Shell32` since the only method available in this class is `ShellExecuteEx()` which is used to launch new processes.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `SelectItemInExplorer` functionality from the [cited example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8682999/1197605) in the question, a *very* basic implementation would look like the following.  Where possible any P/Invoke functionality was rewritten to use as much of SharpShell's existing declarations as possible.

```
using SharpShell.Attributes;
using SharpShell.Interop;
using SharpShell.SharpContextMenu;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SendToFolderRename
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.AllFiles)]
    public class SendToFolderRename : SharpContextMenu
    {
        [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
        private static extern int CreateBindCtx(int reserved, out IntPtr ppbc);

        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        private static extern int SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(IntPtr pidlFolder, uint cidl, IntPtr[] apidl, int dwFlags);

        protected override bool CanShowMenu()
        {
            return true;
        }

        protected override ContextMenuStrip CreateMenu()
        {
            var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
            var itemCountLines = new ToolStripMenuItem
            {
                Text = "Copy files to subfolder"
            };

            itemCountLines.Click += CopyFilesToSubfolder;
            menu.Items.Add(itemCountLines);
            return menu;
        }

        private void CopyFilesToSubfolder(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            string firstSelectedFile = SelectedItemPaths.FirstOrDefault();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstSelectedFile))
                return;

            string currentDirPath = (new FileInfo(firstSelectedFile)).DirectoryName;
            string newDirName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
            string newDirPath = Path.Combine(currentDirPath, newDirName);
            DirectoryInfo newDir = Directory.CreateDirectory(newDirPath);
            foreach (string filePath in SelectedItemPaths)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                string newFilePath = Path.Combine(fileInfo.DirectoryName, newDirName, fileInfo.Name);
                File.Copy(filePath, newFilePath);
            }

            SelectItemInExplorer(IntPtr.Zero, newDirPath, true);
        }

        public static void SelectItemInExplorer(IntPtr hwnd, string itemPath, bool edit)
        {
            if (itemPath == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("itemPath");

            IntPtr folder = PathToAbsolutePIDL(hwnd, Path.GetDirectoryName(itemPath));
            IntPtr file = PathToAbsolutePIDL(hwnd, itemPath);
            try
            {
                SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(folder, 1, new[] { file }, edit ? 1 : 0);
            }
            finally
            {
                Shell32.ILFree(folder);
                Shell32.ILFree(file);
            }
        }

        private static IntPtr GetShellFolderChildrenRelativePIDL(IntPtr hwnd, IShellFolder parentFolder, string displayName)
        {
            IntPtr bindCtx;
            CreateBindCtx(0, out bindCtx);

            uint pchEaten = 0;
            SFGAO pdwAttributes = 0;
            IntPtr ppidl;
            parentFolder.ParseDisplayName(hwnd, bindCtx, displayName, ref pchEaten, out ppidl, ref pdwAttributes);
            return ppidl;
        }

        private static IntPtr PathToAbsolutePIDL(IntPtr hwnd, string path)
        {
            IShellFolder desktopFolder;
            Shell32.SHGetDesktopFolder(out desktopFolder);
            return GetShellFolderChildrenRelativePIDL(hwnd, desktopFolder, path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. I will try it tomorrow (I’ve been busy) and report back if it works. It’d be a bit sad if there isn’t a more SharpShell-y way to do it, but it’s better than nothing :)